# how to sow result multiple word combination match in jtree search filter jquery (multiple word & condition in jtree)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datatable

I have code like this. I am using jtree search fileter.

---

```
$(document).on("keyup paste", "input#groups-quick-filter", function(){
    var tmpStr = $(this).val().replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');
    var arrStr = tmpStr.split(' ');
    var strCnt = "";
    for(i = 0; i < countWords(tmpStr); i++){
        strCnt = strCnt + arrStr[i] + " ";
        //groupsDataTable.jstree("search", arrStr[i]);
        groupsDataTable.jstree(true).search(arrStr[i]);
    }
});
```

---

I have jtree array (nodes) value like this

---

```
1            abc
2            abc xyz
3            xyz abc 
4            testabcxyz
5            test xyz
6            xyz
7            abc test xyz
8            xyzabctest
```

---

Input value in search filter: `abc xyz`  (it gives me.)

---

```
Result 
1            abc xyz
2            xyz abc 
3            testabcxyz
4            test xyz
5            xyz
6            abc test xyz
7            xyzabctest
```

---

I only want results which contain `%abc% & %xyz%` not like `%abc% or %xyz%`. My code give me or result which consider all word.

Comment: Will need some sort of working example to be able to assist further. One thing I noticed, when you use `strCnt = strCnt + arrStr[i] + " ";`, could you not use `strCnt = arrStr.join(" ");` earlier on to make this?

Comment: Created this fiddle for testing: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/6s1q4L6f/

Comment: still i get same result as previously defined.. I want to word which contain %test% and %abc% so as per your solution it will give me ("abc") word also my input : test abc result : abc -(should not there) abc xyz -(should not there -false) xyz abc -(should not there -false) testabcxyz test xyz -(should not there -true) xyz -(should not there -true) abc test xyz xyzabctest *false contain word which should not in search result.i want (%word1% && %word2%) condition in which should include both word in search result

Comment: I want result with &&(AND) condition so logically it should be like i.e. INPUT ("abc test") so list of word contain word (abc && test) should be in result. so word which have not contain either (abc) or (test) should not in result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the `search` plugin, there is an `append` flag:

> append (Boolean) if set to true the results of this search are appended to the previous search

See: https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=search(str%20[,%20skip_async])

With this, I adjusted your original code. Basically we're going to search for each term, separated by spaces, in our data.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/6s1q4L6f/5/

**HTML**

```
Filter:
<input type="text" id="groups-quick-filter">
<span class="clear-button">X</span>
<div id="jstree">
  <ul>
    <li>abc</li>
    <li>abc xyz</li>
    <li>xyz abc</li>
    <li>testabcxyz</li>
    <li>test xyz</li>
    <li>xyz</li>
    <li>abc test xyz</li>
    <li>xyzabctest</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.clear-button {
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
  margin-left: -22px;
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  $("#jstree").jstree({
    "plugins": [
      "search"
    ],
  });
  $(".clear-button").click(function() {
    $("#groups-quick-filter").val("");
    $("#jstree").jstree(true).clear_search();
    $(this).hide();
  })
  $("#groups-quick-filter").keyup(function() {
    $(".clear-button").show();
    var term = $(this).val();
    if (term.length && term.indexOf(' ')) {
      var arrStr = term.split(' ');
      $.each(arrStr, function(k, v) {
        $("#jstree").jstree(true).search(v, true, false, false, true);
      });
    } else {
      $("#jstree").jstree(true).search(term);
    }
  });
});
```

This is based on the example Search shown here: https://www.jstree.com/plugins/

Comment: still i get same result as previously defined.. I want to word which contain %test% and %abc% so as per your solution it will give me ("abc") word also

my input : test abc

result :

Comment: still i get same result as previously defined.. I want to word which contain %test% and %abc% so as per your solution it will give me ("abc") word also

my input : test abc

result :

abc                -(should not there)
abc xyz           -(should not there  -false)
xyz abc          -(should not there  -false)
testabcxyz
test xyz         -(should not there  -true)
xyz                -(should not there  -true)
abc test xyz
xyzabctest

*false contain word which should not in search result.i want (%word1% && %word2%) condition in which should include both word in search result.

Comment: If your input is `test abc`, the logic used is to iterate over each word, searching for that word in the data. For example, `test` will be searched for first. `testabcxyz, test xyz, abc test xyz, xyzabctest` would be highlighted on this first pass. In the second pass, the search will retain the previous results and also now look for `abc`. The second pass will highlight: `abc, abc xyz, xyz abc, testabcxyz, abc test xyz, xyzabctest`. This is the `%word1% && %word2%` logic. Are you sure you do not want `%word1 word2% logic?

Comment: yes dude i understand you point but I want result with &&(AND) condition so logically it should be like i.e. INPUT ("abc test") so list of word contain word (abc && test) should be in result. so word which have not contain either (abc) or (test) should not in result.